# Python Thread Multiprocessing asyncio

Tags: python, многопоточность, asyncio, multiprocessing

Подскажите когда использовать threads, multiprocessing и asyncio? В каких задачах?

Comment: нужна параллельность и для задач cpu-bound = multiprocessing, для io-bound =  threads, а asyncio дает async/await синтаксис, который делает асинхронный код похожим на синхронный, что проще кодировать.

Comment: что проще кодировать - ну не сказал бы)

Comment: @eri проще. намного проще. В питоне async/await не ахти конечно, но когда переводишь синхронный код в асинхронный, то часто хватает пройти и проставить await в нужных местах и все. Без async/await  пришлось бы городить приличный огород с Threads и конечный код сильно бы отличался от оригинала и куда сложнее воспринимался бы

Comment: В питоне нет await внутри синхронной функции - начинается безумное дописывание async везде, но async нельзя дописать в асинхронных серверах - начинается еншуре футуре. хочется выполнить и продолжить сразу, но ран антил комплит уже не пашет - приходится в колбек передавать функцию замыкание, а если там ещё что-то асинхронное - получай колбэк хелл. конечно  оборачивание ответа полностью в футуре работает, но потом нужно представлять где лок, где переключится контекст, что можно перенести в тред... ньюансов массы - код заставляет думать. я бы не сказал что он прощё

Comment: @eri мои слова "дописал await" как бы подразумевают "дописал async". В остальном же "думать нужно всегда", но переписывание проходит легко, либо приходится решать недостатки asyncio (я же и говорю что реализация не ахти по сравнению с c# например). И все равно трудоемкость перехода куда меньше threads варианта, а результат куда более похож на оригинал. А если кому то тяжело - значит он не привык мыслить в async- стиле.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

asyncio и threads используется для задач ввода ввывода. Сетевого, дискового, для общения с медленными программами. Когда нужно обрабатывать очень большое количество соединений лучше подходит асинкио. Треды удобней для взаимодействия с пользователем.

Разница тредов и асинкио в том что asyncio переключает функцию на слове await, а остальные асинхронные функции ставит в очередь, а треды запускаются сразу (кушает больше ресурсов) и их переключает gil в произвольном месте. Тоесть асинхронные функции выполняются по очереди - не параллельно. Асинкио позволяет выполнить другие задачи пока относительно медленное соединение передает данные, когда данные пришли - возвращается к их обработке.

Простой сервер:

```
принял-скачал-обработал-выгрузил-принял-скачал-обработал-выгрузил
```

Сервер на тредах:

```
принял-принял-скачалоба-обработал-обработал-выгрузилоба
```

Сервер на асинкио:

```
принял1 - пока качается 1 принял 2 и начал качать2-пока качается 2 обработал1 - пока выгружается 1 обрабатывается 2 - выгружается 2
```

multiprocessing используется для задачек, где грузится процессор сильнее чем ввод-вывод. Минусом мультипроцессинга является потребление ресурсов для запуска новых процессов и накладные расходы для передачи данных между процессами.

Для задачек где есть много соединений и обработка данных используй [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#executing-code-in-thread-or-process-pools) и [processpoolexecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor).

Comment: Подскажи, пожалуйста. Правильно я понял: функция , которая объявляется с async без ключевого слова await не делает ничего полезного? А именно ключевое слово await говорит что-то типо - вот тут будет ввод/вывод , я пошёл делать , а вы там дальше работаете . Когда get_event_loop видит , что ввод/вывод закончился , функция работает дальше. ?

Comment: Asyncio это такие же треды, но с возможностью явно говорить , что эту часть запускать параллельно? А именно , я могу в await поставить любые вычисления и они будут выполняться на фоне , как поток , пока выполняется остальная часть программы ?

Comment: @BADITP1 асинкио это один тред с прерыванием и переключением на обработку нового коннетка пока идет ввод-вывод на старом

Comment: @BADITP1 да, аваит говорит что можно поделать чтото ещё из конкурентных задач пока ждём ввод-вывод для асинк функции

Comment: @BADITP1 асинкио это не параллельное выполнение, а разбивка на мелкие последовательные операции. Вводвывод там внутри сделан на асинхронных вызовах - проверяется доступность данных через  вызов select, epoll и тп. Пока данных нет выполняется конкурентные функции

Comment: спасибо, все понял